# Show that ${n+k-1 \choose k}={n+k-2\choose k}+{n+k-1 \choose k-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

> Show that ${n+k-1 \choose k}={n+k-2\choose k}+{n+k-1 \choose k-1}$

So I have $${n+k-2\choose k}+{n+k-1 \choose k-1}=\frac{(n+k-2)!}{k!(n+k-2-k)!}+\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(k-1)!(n+k-1-k+1)!}$$

$$=\frac{n+k-2)!(k-1)!(n!)+(n+k-1)!(k!)(n-2)!}{(k!)(k-1)!(n-2)!(n)!}$$

$$=\frac{(n+k-1)!(k-1)!(n-2)![n(n+1)(n+k-1)+k]}{k!(n-2)!(k-1)!(n!)}$$

$$=\frac{(n+k-1)![n(n+1)(n+k-1)+k]}{k!(n!)}$$

From here I'm not sure how to continue. I want to end up with $\frac{(n+k-1)!}{k!(n+k-1-k)!}$

Comment: I think the "equality" in your title is incorrect as written

Comment: @J. W. Tanner Oh. Well this is the problem given from my notes. How did you determine it isn't true?

Comment: In the first term of the right side of the equation, it should be $n+k-2$ over $k-1$, not k

Comment: The identity that you should be trying to reach for is equivalent to $\binom{a}{b}=\binom{a-1}{b-1}+\binom{a-1}{b}$, the so called [Pascal's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule).  In your case $\binom{n+k-1}{k}=\binom{n+k-2}{k}+\binom{n+k\color{red}{-2}}{k-1}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, $${n+k-1 \choose k}={n+k-2\choose k}+{n+k-2 \choose k-1}$$

This is because $\binom ak=\binom{a-1}k+\binom{a-1}{k-1}$ where $a=n+k-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a counterexample to show that the "equation" in your title is not true

(no wonder you were having trouble proving it!):

with $n=4$ and $k=2$, $$\binom52\ne\binom42+\binom51$$ since $10\ne6+5$.

You should have more success proving that $$\binom{n+k-1}{k}=\binom{n+k-2}{k}+\binom{n+k-\color{red}2}{k-1}.$$